# Identifying the square $DEFG$ and than finding the value of its perimeter.

Tags: geometry, triangles, plane-geometry, geometric-construction

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle and $DEFG$ be a square, where $D, E$ points are located on $AB$ and $AC$ or their extension line. $F, G$ points are located on $BC$ or the extension of $BC$. The perpendicular distance from $A$ on $BC$ is $2$ units and $BC$ = $6$ units. What is the value of the perimeter of $DEFG$?

Here, I'm little bit confused about the exact location of the points $D, E, F, G$ respectively. I noticed that this 4 points could locate on either on the side of the triangle or on their extension line. So, I thought that the length of the square would be variable according to the various construction of the triangle $ABC$. I couldn't find a way to figure it out. Therefore, I need some help about how to construct that square with keeping its length constant with above mentioned condition.

*The error is highly excusable*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance from $A$ to the  nearest side of the square is $|x-2|$, where $x$ is a side of the square.

Thus, by the similarity we obtain:
$$\frac{|x-2|}{2}=\frac{x}{6},$$ which gives
$$x=\frac{3}{2}$$ and the answer  $6$ or
$$x=3$$ and the answer $12$.

Comment: @Anirban Niloy I don't know to draw in the net. Try to draw the obtuse-angled triangle, $\measuredangle BAC>90^{\circ}.$ The altitude from $A$ is $2$ and $BC=6$.  Now, easy to draw our square.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg You assumed that the distance to the nearest side is $2-x$. That means that $DE$ is on the same side of $A$ as $BC$. You also have a solution on the opposite side. The distance is then $x-2$ instead, which yields the solution $x=3$, with perimeter $12$

Comment: @Andrei I fixed. Thank you!